# Rails 3 routes for single controller and multiple resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have multiple resources (`:countries, :states, :schools` etc.) but would like a single "Dashboard" controller to handle all the actions.

I would like to be able to do the following:

`countries_path` would direct me to a `show_countries` action in the `DashboardController` and be accesible by `'/dashboard/countries`.

Likewise for states, schools, etc.

I've read up on Rails routing and have been messing around with various options. I ended up with the following in my `routes.rb` file:

```
scope "toolbox" do
  resources :countries, :controller => "toolbox", :only => :index do
    get 'show_countries', :on => :collection
  end

  ...
end
```

Running `rake routes` gives me the following for the code above:

```
show_countries_countries GET    /toolbox/countries/show_countries(.:format)  {:action=>"show_countries", :controller=>"toolbox"}
countries GET    /toolbox/countries(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"toolbox"}
```

I've tried this:

```
scope "toolbox" do
  resources :countries, :controller => "toolbox", :only => :index, :action => "show_countries"
end
```

only to get this route:

```
countries GET    /toolbox/countries(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"toolbox"}
```

What I really want is this:

```
countries GET    /toolbox/countries(.:format)  {:action=>"show_countries", :controller=>"toolbox"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to think outside of the 'resources' box:

```
scope "toolbox", :controller => :toolbox do
  get 'countries' => :show_countries
  get 'states' => :show_states
  get 'schools' => :show_shools
end
```

Should output routes like this:

```
countries GET /toolbox/countries(.:format) toolbox#show_countries
```